# Select Options are Not Selectable - Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I am using the Jquery Autocomplete function to pull data from my database, via a Coldfusion CFC, and autocomplete the text as the user types. That part is working and my selectlist is populating as expected.

However I cannot select any of the items. I've found a couple similar posts on SO, but none seem to fix my issues. Can anyone find the issue here?

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $( "#assign_customer_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: "cfcs/customers_lookup.cfc?method=lookupCustomers&returnformat=json",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('##assign_customer_name').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });           
    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML element:

```
<H2>Please choose a customer:</h2>
<input autofocus size="50" name="assign_customer_name" id="assign_customer_name" tabindex="0" required type="text" autocomplete="off"> <br /><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a typo in my ajax. Here is the updated code:

```
<!---Autocomplete for customer name--->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#assign_customer_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: "cfcs/customers_lookup.cfc?method=lookupCustomers&returnformat=json",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#assign_customer_name').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
```